# Multivariate Caluclus, harmonic, Divergence Theorem, Flux

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator, multivalued-functions

[image]

Facts that would be helpful to the proof:
[image]

I honestly have no idea how to begin/proceed since we rarely look at proofs or abstract idea "near the origin". We have only done a lot of parameterizations and flux integrals, etc.

Any help or sketch of proof would be appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just give you an idea for showing that $||\nabla g||^2 = 0 $ inside a sufficiently small sphere $S_1$, which means $g$ is a constant inside the sphere (near the origin).

Part (a) is nothing but the statement that $f$ is a minimum at the origin,

Part (b) is the [Green's first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_identities), roughly proven by using integration by parts.

Now, $g$ is a harmonic function, $\Delta g= 0$, then $f=g-C$ is also a harmonic function, where $C$ is a positive constant which is large enough to ***make $f<0$ inside the region $S_1$***

Using the identity, from part (b) and $\Delta g=\Delta f= 0$,
$$\int_{S_1} f \nabla f \cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{x\in S_1}||\nabla g||^2 dV$$

The right hand side is obviously $\ge 0$, what about the left hand side? (remember that by construction $g<0$ for $x \in S_1$)

I think you can figure this out by yourself. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mastrok! I just want to confirm that g <0 by how we construct it and grad(g)dS >0 from part a). and so the integrand in the left side is less than 0 making the integral less than 0. Am I correct? My other question is how did you assume f is a harmonic function? I know g is by assumption. :)

Comment: I changed $f$ and $g$ since your original question is asking for $g$, but once the statement holds for $g$ then it holds for $f$ as well. You can always construct that, just choose a positive $C$ such that it is greater than the maximum value of $g$. It is obvious that for two functions differ by a constant, one of them being harmonic means both are harmonic. Now the l.h.s. is positive while the r.h.s is negative so you can conclude that $||\nabla f||^2=0$ inside the region.

Comment: If this is helpful to you, please upvote or make it the answer.